# What is the meaning of "rendition" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "rendition" mean in the following paragraph?

> References to the pea jacket appear in American newspapers at least as early as the 1720s, and modern renditions still maintain the original design and composition.

This comes from the article about pea coat at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pea_coat).

I have an idea that this could have something to do with the design of the coat? I could not find a definition that's appropriate to the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google gives the following definition:

> ren·di·tion/renˈdiSHən/
>
> Noun:
>
> 1. A performance or interpretation, esp. of a dramatic role or piece of music.
> 2. A visual representation or reproduction.

The applicable sense here is #2. Modern pea-coats are representations or reproductions of the original designs.